# System crashed during glibc compile, refuses to compile again even after remaking build directory

Tags: linux, glibc, linux-from-scratch

I am chrooted into the temporary system (/tools). During the compile of glibc (step 6.9 of LFS), my computer unexpectedly shut down. After booting back up, remaking the build directory, running configure and make, it fails. Here is the log:

```
root:/sources/glibc-2.24/build# make
make -r PARALLELMFLAGS="" -C .. objdir=`pwd` all
make[1]: Entering directory '/sources/glibc-2.24'
make  subdir=csu -C csu ..=../ subdir_lib
make[2]: Entering directory '/sources/glibc-2.24/csu'
gawk -f ../scripts/gen-as-const.awk ../sysdeps/x86_64/nptl/tcb-offsets.sym \
| gcc -S -o /sources/glibc-2.24/build/tcb-offsets.hT3 -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline  -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -g -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition     -ftls-model=initial-exec      -I../include -I/sources/glibc-2.24/build/csu  -I/sources/glibc-2.24/build  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/include -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/nptl  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu/include -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I.. -I../libio -I.   -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include /sources/glibc-2.24/build/libc-modules.h -DMODULE_NAME=libc -include ../include/libc-symbols.h       -x c - \
        -MD -MP -MF /sources/glibc-2.24/build/tcb-offsets.h.dT -MT '/sources/glibc-2.24/build/tcb-offsets.h.d /sources/glibc-2.24/build/tcb-offsets.h'
In file included from ../sysdeps/generic/hp-timing-common.h:42:0,
                 from ../sysdeps/x86_64/hp-timing.h:38,
                 from ../include/libc-internal.h:7,
                 from ../sysdeps/x86_64/nptl/tls.h:29,
                 from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h:24,
                 from <stdin>:1:
../sysdeps/generic/_itoa.h:32:25: error: "LONG_MAX" is not defined [-Werror=undef]
 # define _ITOA_NEEDED  (LONG_MAX != LLONG_MAX)
                         ^
../sysdeps/generic/_itoa.h:97:6: note: in expansion of macro '_ITOA_NEEDED'
 #if !_ITOA_NEEDED
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [../Makerules:224: /sources/glibc-2.24/build/tcb-offsets.h] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/sources/glibc-2.24/csu'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:214: csu/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/sources/glibc-2.24'
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
root:/sources/glibc-2.24/build#
```

It seems like limits.h doesn't exist, but I checked, and it does indeed exist.

```
root:/usr/include/linux# ls | grep "limits.h"
limits.h
```

EDIT: I catted limits.h and noticed that LONG_MAX indeed was not included in the file. Here is the file:

```
#ifndef _LINUX_LIMITS_H
#define _LINUX_LIMITS_H

#define NR_OPEN         1024

#define NGROUPS_MAX    65536    /* supplemental group IDs are available */
#define ARG_MAX       131072    /* # bytes of args + environ for exec() */
#define LINK_MAX         127    /* # links a file may have */
#define MAX_CANON        255    /* size of the canonical input queue */
#define MAX_INPUT        255    /* size of the type-ahead buffer */
#define NAME_MAX         255    /* # chars in a file name */
#define PATH_MAX        4096    /* # chars in a path name including nul */
#define PIPE_BUF        4096    /* # bytes in atomic write to a pipe */
#define XATTR_NAME_MAX   255    /* # chars in an extended attribute name */
#define XATTR_SIZE_MAX 65536    /* size of an extended attribute value (64k) */
#define XATTR_LIST_MAX 65536    /* size of extended attribute namelist (64k) */

#define RTSIG_MAX         32

#endif
root:/usr/include/linux# ls | grep "limits.h"
limits.h
root:/usr/include/linux# cat limits.h 
#ifndef _LINUX_LIMITS_H
#define _LINUX_LIMITS_H

#define NR_OPEN         1024

#define NGROUPS_MAX    65536    /* supplemental group IDs are available */
#define ARG_MAX       131072    /* # bytes of args + environ for exec() */
#define LINK_MAX         127    /* # links a file may have */
#define MAX_CANON        255    /* size of the canonical input queue */
#define MAX_INPUT        255    /* size of the type-ahead buffer */
#define NAME_MAX         255    /* # chars in a file name */
#define PATH_MAX        4096    /* # chars in a path name including nul */
#define PIPE_BUF        4096    /* # bytes in atomic write to a pipe */
#define XATTR_NAME_MAX   255    /* # chars in an extended attribute name */
#define XATTR_SIZE_MAX 65536    /* size of an extended attribute value (64k) */
#define XATTR_LIST_MAX 65536    /* size of extended attribute namelist (64k) */

#define RTSIG_MAX         32

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `#ifndef _LINUX_LIMITS_H`

This is `include/linux/limits.h`. The `LONG_MAX` is supposed to come from `include/limits.h`, which is a *different* file.

It's likely that your sources got corrupted after unclean shutdown. You should restore them from a pristine copy.